# How can I solve this & reach better performance

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We are using an ERP system, here is one sql query below - and it's working:

(it's using an old syntax)

```
(select last_name||' '||name||'   '||to_char(datum_p,'DD.MM.YYYY') 
from
  (
   select co.kod_id, bu.last_name, bu.name, cl.datum_p, ctl.rid, md.short_name 
   from ord_odb_l cl, ord_odb_o co, b_users bu, ct_l ctl, m_delivery md
   where co.rid_o = cl.rid and bu.id = cl.operator and cl.delivery_place = md.rid 
   and cl.operator not IN (161,245,46,120,43,184) order by cl.datum_p desc
  ) aa 
where aa.kod_id = orders.SK_ID and aa.rid = orders.rid_ct_a 
and aa.short_name = orders.md and aa.datum_p > orders.datum_ok and rownum = 1)
```

I want to use an `NVL function` to select names & datum between orders - distribution:

(but i think, it's not possible with subquery or i failed, **because i get error** - `missing right parenthesis`)

```
(select last_name||' '||name||'   '||to_char(datum_p,'DD.MM.YYYY') 
from 
  (
   NVL(
    (select co.kod_id, bu.last_name, bu.name, cl.datum_p, ctl.rid, md.short_name
     from ord_odb_l cl, ord_odb_o co, b_users bu, ct_l ctl, m_delivery md 
     where co.rid_o = cl.rid and bu.id = cl.operator and cl.delivery_place = md.rid 
     and cl.operator not IN (161,245,46,120,43,184) order by cl.datum_p desc),

     (select vo.kod_id, bu.last_name, bu.name, vl.datum_p, ctl.rid, md.short_name 
     from distrb_l vl, distrb_o vo, b_users bu, ct_l ctl, m_delivery md
     where vo.rid_o = vl.rid and bu.id = cl.operator and cl.delivery_place = md.rid 
     and cl.operator not IN (161,245,46,120,43,184) order by vl.datum_p desc)
      )
   ) aa 
where aa.kod_id = orders.SK_ID and aa.rid = orders.rid_ct_a 
and aa.short_name = orders.md and aa.datum_p > orders.datum_ok and rownum = 1
)
```

**If have to, we can join `distrb_l` and `ord_odb_l`, too:**

```
(select * from ord_odb_l cl join distrb_l vl ON cl.rid = vl.rid_v)
```

**for help:**

We have tables: `ord_odb_l` (orders header) and `ord_odb_o` (orders contents), `distrb_l` (distribution header) and `distrb_o` (distribution contents), `b_users` (user table), `ct_l` (pricing table), `m_delivery` (delivery table)

Columns: `kod_id` (number), `last.name - name` (varchar2), `datum_p` (date), `rid` (number), `short_name` (varchar2), `operator` (number), `delivery_place` (number)

Actual table: `orders`

I know it's bit a complex & hard to read, but how can i solve this and reach a better performance ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: NVL works on a single value, not the result of a more complex query. Now, because your code uses a NVL function in the wrong way, it's hard to determine what it is you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `nvl` from two `select`s returning many columns.

You want to find newest date and matching names. `Union all` data from both `select`s then `order by` and `rownum` can do it.

Rows from `ord_odb_l` have higher priority, rows from `distrb_l` are secondary data source. So, only if there is no data in first `select` query will return something from second:

```
(select last_name||' '||name||'   '||to_char(datum_p,'DD.MM.YYYY') 
  from (
    select 1 src, co.kod_id, bu.last_name, bu.name, cl.datum_p, ctl.rid, md.short_name
      from ord_odb_l  cl
      join ord_odb_o  co on co.rid_o = cl.rid 
      join b_users    bu on bu.id = cl.operator 
      cross join ct_l ctl
      join m_delivery md on cl.delivery_place = md.rid
      where cl.operator not IN (161,245,46,120,43,184) 
    union all 
    select 2 src, vo.kod_id, bu.last_name, bu.name, vl.datum_p, ctl.rid, md.short_name 
      from distrb_l   vl
      join distrb_o   vo on vo.rid_o = vl.rid
      join b_users    bu on bu.id = cl.operator
      cross join ct_l ctl
      join m_delivery md on cl.delivery_place = md.rid
      where cl.operator not IN (161,245,46,120,43,184) 
      order by src, datum_p desc) aa 
  where aa.kod_id = orders.SK_ID and aa.rid = orders.rid_ct_a 
    and aa.short_name = orders.md and aa.datum_p > orders.datum_ok and rownum = 1)
```

Your query is the part of bigger one, perhaps subselect, because we don't see here what is `orders` etc.. Probably you can simplify this task, but without the whole image it's hard to say more. Anyway this should work. Notice that I changed syntax to `join` form. Table `ct_l` has no joining condition in your queries, so used `cross join`, is this correct? There was also `derlivery` instead of `delivery`.

One more thing. I assumed that rows from first table have higher priority because this suggests your code. If you want the row with newest date, no matter which table, then use `order by datum_p desc` instead of `order by src, datum_p desc`.

Also, in Oracle 12 you can use `fetch first row only`, but question is tagged as Oracle 11g.

As you noticed it's hard to answer such question without data access, structure (and without 100% knowing expectations), but maybe this will help.

Comment: Man, You are awesome. Thats what i wanted. Many thanks. ...yeap, the derlivery was my mistake here.. (on stackoverflow).